# Changing an object's value according to user Input

Tags: java

I am trying to figure a way in how to change an object's value. I've made a class in which it contains set and get for the object and 3 sorts of values being PRICE, QUANTITY and NAME.

The price and name are already set in the test class

```
System.out.println("How many would you like?");
String quantity = s1.nextLine();
quantity = food1.setQuantity();
```

`quantity = food1.setQuantity();` is wrong.
 How do I change it according to how much quantity the user wants?

Comment: `food1.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantity));`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `food1.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantity))` ? If it does not compile, you should read a tutorial about providing getters and setters for your classes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with:

```
quantity = food1.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantity));
```

instead of:

```
quantity = food1.setQuantity();
```

Comment: Note for OP: setters typically return `void`

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to sound harsh, but programming isn't magic.  Look at what you're doing:

```
 String quantity = s1.nextLine();
 quantity = food1.setQuantity();
```

You're overwriting the string with what one would hope to be a `void` set method.  Instead, the method should be a `void` set method, which accepts an integer, so you would do the following (assuming proper function implementation):

```
 String quantity = s1.nextLine();
 food1.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantity));
```

Not sure if you learned Exception handling yet, but you should wrap this in a try/catch if you have.  If not, you can use regular expressions to see if it's an integer, if that is necessary.  Odds are this is a class assignment, and you're probably assuming that the input is valid or using exception handling.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I found the answer through this. I parsed the value and assigned it to a variable "a" and stored it in food1.setQuantity(a);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that the quantity is supposed to be an integer, you could write this:

```
String quanity = s1. nextLine();
//check that quanitity is a valid number before trying to parse it as a number
if(quantity.matches("\\d+"))
{
    food1.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantity));
}else
{
    System.out.println("The quantity you entered is not a valid number.");
}
```